# Dishes on menus and capitalising in naratives

Tags: capitalization

1. "I'll have a mixed salad," or how about, 2. "I'll have the Mixed Salad." What about, 3. "I'll have the mesclun salad." If in the narrative the speaker is ordering directly from the menu, would it be necessary to use capitals as in example 2. A mixed salad is a very general term but what if the speaker asks for the mesclun salad. A mesclun salad is clearly defined by it's name, so would this need capitalisation.

Comment: This question deals with the finer points of correct capitalisation and asks about a subtle interpretation of what is a proper noun in context. I have looked at the list of general references and cannot see how my question could be adequately answered using them. I have recently had a satisfactory answer from another source. I will be posting another question to test whether the question could be answered as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

This comes down to the usage of capitals in general.

Capitalize proper nouns.

If you name your mesclun salad on the menu, Mesclun Salad is now a proper noun.

If it is not named, but rather you have a heading Salads, and there are columns of ingredients to mix and match. Then, asking for a mesclun salad with croutons and bacon, is not capitalized.   It is not the name of the dish now, hence not a proper noun.