# "I'll have the Mesclun Salad," please

Tags: grammar, nouns

"I'll have the Mesclun Salad, please." Note the capitals. This question concerns the definition of a proper noun and how context can subtly change this. Please refer to former question. It is a question dealing with grammar and nouns, which is Stack Exchange topic. My main question at this point is how could I find an answer to this question using the list of references as recommended: I'm still working on it.

Comment: [Proper noun](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/proper-noun?q=proper+noun) is not defined as you have defined it in your other question.

Comment: Please, don't think that I was annoyed that my original question was put on hold.

Comment: [This is the previous question referenced.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/158069/dishes-on-menus-and-capitalising-in-naratives)  What was wrong with @DavidM's answer/ what more is unclear?

Comment: Does this question concern the definition of a proper noun, or are you asking how to find an answer using the recommended list of references? One is valid here, the other is a [Meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com) question.

Comment: I am not confused. I have said that context can change what is a noun or proper noun, and the original question, which was well answered by @DavidM, was concerning this. There are very many variations when it comes to menus and dishes, a minefield of punctuation issues, for example; A Big Mac, a Waldorf salad, a spaghetti Bolognaise (Bologna is actually a place), or an English breakfast, or perhaps, "I'll have the English Breakfast." I regard that my question was perfectly ok. I wouldn't have asked, "What's in the Game Pie" because I could have looked that up in the dictionary.

Comment: "This question concerns..." and "My main question at this point is..." Which is it?

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be confused here:

> context can subtly change this

You are not going to find answers in reference material regarding this because it's just not true. There is no mysterious juju happening; it's pretty straightforward.

Proper nouns are capitalized. These are names given to specific things. Here is a basic example:

> This is Fido. Fido is the name of my dog.

I believe your confusion happens when a given name is *the same* as a normal word. For example, I could decided to name my dog "Dog". He is still a dog, but he is named Dog.

> This is Dog. Dog is the name of my dog.

Note that there is no subtle context magic, simply a choice: am I using the specific given name (Dog), or referring to the thing (dog).

Comment: Well I'll be doggoned, that's a ruff answer.

Comment: @RonanMurphy thanks, I was afraid I was doggedly hounding the questioner.

Answer (score 1):

There is no capitalization in language. That's entirely an arbitrary convention of writing.

And that is a transcription of a spoken sentence. There were no capitals in the original.

The only reason why one would write that sentence would be to report the speech,
and in reporting speech one follows whatever spelling conventions one finds proper.

That's all, really. Stop thinking of writing as language, and start listening instead.

Comment: So, when transcribing the name of a proper noun don't capitalize it?  "john said something i didn't believe," commented

Comment: What I said was "in reporting speech one follows whatever spelling conventions one finds proper". If one finds capitalization proper, one capitalizes; if one doesn't, one doesn't. If one doesn't know, one has no business transcribing speech.

Comment: OK, but if there is a *named* item on a menu, it becomes a proper noun.  And, the proper way to report the usage of a proper noun is to capitalize said item.  Hence I don't believe that there "were no capitals in the original."  I agree that there are *NO SPOKEN* capitals.  But, I think you need to make this point clearer for people who may not understand the nuance of what you are saying.  Most people understand *language* to mean both spoken and written.

Comment: Thanks, David M. The most concise answer that I have got so far.

Comment: @DavidM: There's no nuance in what I said (which is what I wrote, as close as I can get) at all. What "most people understand" about what _language_ means turns out to be wrong. This is not a nuance; this is a fact. The sooner people learn this fact, the quicker they can dispel their confusion. Concealing facts from people asking questions is not the best educational or scientific policy, and as a teacher and a scientist, I have no respect at all for that policy.

Comment: @JohnLawler adding the word spoken in front of language doesn't make it wrong.  And, ignoring common usage defeats the entire point of language.  What term do you prefer for the written form, then?

Comment: When one is discussing a natural phenomenon, and a technological representation of that phenomenon  -- say birds and bird paintings -- and one wishes to use the same term (_robin_) for both of them for some reason. The usual convention is that the representation is to be distinguished from the real phenomenon, when such a distinction is warranted. In particular, one should never confuse a painting of a bird with a living bird; they don't work the same and they aren't the same kind of thing at all. Confusing them is at the root of most of the questions we get here.